# Как проверить доступ к интернету?

Tags: android

Подскажите, как проверить доступность интернет соединения? Именно доступность, бывают ситуации когда интернет включен но не дает трафик(к примеру при нулевом балансе на счету)

Или проще самому делать проверку на подключение к серверу мол, если интернет включен и сервер отвечает то всё нормально но, если интернет включен но сервер молчит значит нет доступа к интернету?

Comment: Хорошо сформулированный вопрос -- половина ответа! Всё верно, если вас волнует только доступ к конкретным хостам, их и проверяйте. Может стоять выборочная блокировка чего угодно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Создайте метод:

```
public boolean isOnline() {  
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    int exitValue = -1;

    try {
        Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
        exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
    }
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException ignored) {}

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return netInfo != null && exitValue == 0 && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Разрешение в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Пример:**

```
if(isOnline) //если интернет есть
else //если нет
```

Comment: это немного не то, в данном случае идет проверка "Включен интернет или нет?" Если он активен то проверка пройдет успешно но, не факт что трафик пойдет

Comment: @Heaven, обновил ответ